# Dynamically create/populate QTableWidgets in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I want to dynamically create and populate QTableWidgets on PyQt4.

My goal is to display different sets of data on separated tables (placed on different tabs in a QTabWidget). The data sets names and their number are not predictable, I cannot pre-create the tables/tabs in Qt Designer.

I did not find any other post about this matter, except for reproducing existing widgets (mostly `QPushButtons` but I apologize if this problem has already been brought up.

As you can see on the picture below, I was able to create the tabs, give them a name dynamically (here let’s say tab_1, tab_2 and tab_3) and add widgets to them.

However, when I try to populate the tables it turns out that I am populating the same table in my different tabs (the tables in each tab are referred as the same QTableWidget).

Function:

```
for i,s in enumerate(dataSets):

    tab_name = str(s)
    tab = QWidget()

    self.tabWidget.addTab(tab, tab_name)     

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    label_1=QLabel()
    spacerItem1 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)

    label_1.setText(u"Data set:")

    # Up to here, it looks like everything works fine

    self.Table_1="Table_%s" % str(i)     #Table_1, Table_2, Table_3, ...

    self.Table_1 = QtGui.QTableWidget()
    self.Table_1.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 150))
    self.Table_1.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    self.Table_1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8(str(self.Table_1)))
    self.Table_1.setColumnCount(0)
    self.Table_1.setRowCount(0)

    layout.addSpacing(20)
    layout.addWidget(label_1)
    layout.addWidget(self.Table_1)
    self.populateTable_1()

self.tabWidget.setLayout(layout)
```

The problem comes from these two lines as the name associated with the `QtGui.QTableWidget()` is `self.Table_1` and not its value.

```
self.Table_1="Table_%s" % str(i)     #Table_1, Table_2, Table_3, ...

self.Table_1 = QtGui.QTableWidget()
```

I tried `setattr` as well, but without any success, the tables are created but I get an error when I call `self.Table_1` to populate it.

Dear Python Gurus, I thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: what is `populateTable_1`? is there `populateTable_2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set properties with a dynamic name you must use `setattr()`:

```
for i,s in enumerate(dataSets):
    tab_name = str(s)

    tab = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(tab)

    label=QLabel(u"Data set:")

    tableName = "Table_{}".format(i)     #Table_1, Table_2, Table_3, ...
    table = QtGui.QTableWidget(0, 0)
    table.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 150))
    table.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    table.setObjectName(_fromUtf8(str(tableName)))
    layout.addSpacing(20)
    layout.addWidget(label)
    layout.addWidget(table)

    setattr(tableName, table)
    self.tabWidget.addTab(tab, tab_name)
```

if there is a method for tab n-th there is also a method `populateTable_n` then you must use `getattr()`:

```
getattr(self, "populateTable_{}".format(i))()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I implemented your modifications but the tables still display the same data.
I am using a single method to populate all the tables, it grabs the data it needs in a nested dictionary for each table.

Comment: @AlanB. 
If you provide a [mcve] I could help you correctly since I could test your code.

Comment: @AlanB. please do not put code in the comments, take the time and provide a [mcve], try to help now only generate a waste of time, when you provide the MCVE I will be happy to help

Comment: Sorry about that, I deleted my comment.

Comment: I solved the problem using your method @eyllanesc, I wasn't using `getattr()` properly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You always overwrite the attribute `Table_1` with a new instance of `QtGui.QTableWidget`. If you want multiple table you have several paths to go. Either you can have several attributes like @eyllanesc proposed or you can simply create a "container" - or `list` in my example -  of tables for the same purpose.

```
self.Table = []
self.label = []

for i,s in enumerate(dataSets):

    tab_name = str(s)

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.label.append( QLabel() )

    self.label[i].setText(u"Data set:")

    # Up to here, it looks like everything works fine

    self.Table.append( QtGui.QTableWidget() )
    self.Table[i].setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 150))
    self.Table[i].setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    self.Table[i].setObjectName(_fromUtf8(tab_name))   # Why not use the name of the "dataSet"?
    self.Table[i].setColumnCount(0)
    self.Table[i].setRowCount(0)

    layout.addSpacing(20)
    layout.addWidget(self.label[i])
    layout.addWidget(self.Table[i])
    self.populateTable(i)   # You must change the input arguments of this method and provide
                            # the access to the elements within the list inside of this method,
                            # in order to use it like here.

self.tabWidget.setLayout(layout)
```

---

I also deleted every line that does not have any effect on the tables themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your help, eyllanesc method seems a bit more straightforward to me but I'll look into yours if I can't get it to work properly